# R. Pairwise distances between two point patterns on a linear network (crossdist.lpp) displays: "Error in order(Yseg0, tY) : argument 2 is not a vector

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

I've been trying for 3 days to find out where the problem came from but I am a beginner in R working on the re-use of interesting scripts for my work like [functions of EAA presentations](https://gist.github.com/JGravier/08490477b95598ac44d4a1d31c8e67f2).
I create a new R file.

```
#### Calculating distances on observed point patterns ####
  ## creation of an lpp object
  observed_lpp1 <- spatstat.linnet::lpp(
    X = spatstat.geom::as.ppp(X = pp1 %>% dplyr::select(geometry)),
    L = maptools::as.linnet.SpatialLines(X = as(network, "Spatial"))
  )
  
  observed_lpp2 <- spatstat.linnet::lpp(
    X = spatstat.geom::as.ppp(X = pp2 %>% dplyr::select(geometry)),
    L = maptools::as.linnet.SpatialLines(X = as(network, "Spatial"))
  )
  
  ## calculating shortest paths for observed data
  matrix_observed_dist_pi_p <- spatstat.linnet::crossdist.lpp(X = observed_lpp1, Y = observed_lpp2)
  
  observed_dist <- matrix_observed_dist_pi_p %>%
    tibble::as_tibble() %>%
    tibble::rowid_to_column(var = "pp1") %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -pp1, names_to = "pp2", values_to = "dist_pi_p") %>%
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(dist_pi_p)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(pp2 = stringr::str_replace_all(string = pp2, pattern = "V", replacement = ""))
```

I received an error message at the line
`matrix_observed_dist_pi_p <- spatstat.linnet::crossdist.lpp(X = observed_lpp1, Y = observed_lpp2)`

> Error in order(Yseg0, tY) : argument 2 is not a vector
> In addition: Warning message:
> In as.data.frame.hyperframe(x$data[, chosen, drop = FALSE]) :
> 1 variable discarded in conversion to data frame

I am currently working with R.4.2 because I needed to use maptools::as.linnet.SpatialLines.

I tried to get my observed_lpp2 as a data frame and there was no data (empty lpp)

Comment: Please supply the data objects `pp1` and `pp2` so that we can diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution but still don't really understand. The problem came from observed_lpp2 code lines, i replaced by observed_lpp1 code lines and changing the variable lpp and it worked.

I let the post here in case someone faces the same issue but otherwise it can be deleted by the administrators as necessary!

Have a g'day!

Comment: Howzit Anne! Welcome to SO and thanks for answering your own question. Would you mind updating this answer with the code you ended up with? I guess it would be helpful to understand it better

Answer (score 1):

Tip: When you get an error message in R, immediately type `traceback()`. This will tell you where the error was detected, and will give many clues.

This error is occurring because the internal format of the object `observed_lpp2` is corrupted somehow.

I can't diagnose the cause further, without an example where the problem occurs. So **please provide a minimal working example,** that is, a simple data example and R script which causes the problem to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
I investigated and it came from the linear network (lpp2). I cleaned

- the raw data (topology and short segments),
- rebuilt ways (using Morpheo plug-in in QGIS)
- mafa_geom_to_segment: https://jgravier.github.io/mafa/reference/mafa_geom_to_segment.html
- st_cast function
  Then it worked.

Note: I used explode lines from QGIS processings and it was not working whereas the number of segments was identical.

Most of the "inf" distances were corrected then.